# Запись структуры в файл (с)

Tags: c, файлы, структуры

Записать структуру device  в файл А (не записывая каждый елемент, как это сделала я):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct device {
    int roll;
    char name[20];

    int prize;
    int guarantee;
    int voltage;
    int amperage;
    int frequency;
}s[6];
struct products {

}p[15];
int main( ) {

    FILE *f1;
    FILE *f2;
    f1=fopen("A.txt", "w+");
    s[0].roll=1;
    fprintf(f1, "\n №%i ", s[0].roll);
    s[0].name[20]="Kitchen blender";
    fprintf(f1, "Kitchen blender\t");
    s[0].prize=750;
    fprintf(f1, "price:%i hrn\t", s[0].prize );    // hrivnas
    s[0].guarantee=6;  //months
    fprintf(f1, "guarantee:%i mon\t", s[0].guarantee );
    s[0].voltage=220;
    fprintf(f1, "\tvoltage:%i V\t", s[0].voltage );
    s[0].amperage=60;
    fprintf(f1, "amperage:%i A\t", s[0].amperage );
    s[0].frequency=400;
    fprintf(f1, "frequency:%i Hz\t", s[0].frequency );

    s[1].roll=2;
    fprintf(f1, "\n №%i ", s[1].roll);
    s[1].name[20]="Kitchen mixer";
    fprintf(f1, "Kitchen mixer\t");
    s[1].prize=620;     // hrivnas
    fprintf(f1, "price:%i hrn\t", s[1].prize );
    s[1].guarantee=4;   //months
    fprintf(f1, "guarantee:%i mon\t", s[1].guarantee );
    s[1].voltage=220;
    fprintf(f1, "\tvoltage:%i V\t", s[1].voltage );
    s[1].amperage=40;
    fprintf(f1, "amperage:%i A\t", s[1].amperage );
    s[1].frequency=320;
    fprintf(f1, "frequency:%i Hz\t", s[1].frequency );

    s[2].roll=3;
    fprintf(f1, "\n №%i ", s[2].roll);
    s[2].name[20]="Coffee machine";
    fprintf(f1, "Coffee machine\t");
    s[2].prize=950;     // hrivnas
    fprintf(f1, "price:%i hrn\t", s[2].prize );
    s[2].guarantee=12;   //months
    fprintf(f1, "guarantee:%i mon\t", s[2].guarantee );
    s[2].voltage=220;
    fprintf(f1, "voltage:%i V\t", s[2].voltage );
    s[2].amperage=110;
    fprintf(f1, "amperage:%i A\t", s[2].amperage );
    s[2].frequency=380;
    fprintf(f1, "frequency:%i Hz\t", s[2].frequency );

    s[3].roll=4;
    fprintf(f1, "\n №%i ", s[3].roll);
    s[3].name[20]="Multi-cooker";
    fprintf(f1, "Multi-cooker");
    s[3].prize=1130;     // hrivnas
    fprintf(f1, "\tprice:%i hrn\t", s[3].prize );
    s[3].guarantee=12;   //months
    fprintf(f1, "guarantee:%i mon\t", s[3].guarantee );
    s[3].voltage=220;
    fprintf(f1, "voltage:%i V\t", s[3].voltage );
    s[3].amperage=150;
    fprintf(f1, "amperage:% iA\t", s[3].amperage );
    s[3].frequency=500;
    fprintf(f1, "frequency:%i Hz\t", s[3].frequency );

    s[4].roll=5;
    fprintf(f1, "\n №%i ", s[4].roll);
    s[4].name[20]="Double boiler";
    fprintf(f1, "Double boiler");
    s[4].prize=530;     // hrivnas
    fprintf(f1, "\tprice:%i hrn\t", s[4].prize );
    s[4].guarantee=3;   //months
    fprintf(f1, "guarantee:%i mon\t", s[4].guarantee );
    s[4].voltage=220;
    fprintf(f1, "\tvoltage:%i V\t", s[4].voltage );
    s[4].amperage=550;
    fprintf(f1, "amperage:%i A\t", s[4].amperage );
    s[4].frequency=310;
    fprintf(f1, "frequency:%i Hz\t", s[4].frequency );

    s[5].roll=6;
    fprintf(f1, "\n №%i ", s[5].roll);
    s[5].name[20]="Coffee grinder";
    fprintf(f1, "Coffee grinder" );
    s[5].prize=530;     // hrivnas
    fprintf(f1, "\tprice:%i hrn\t", s[5].prize );
    s[5].guarantee=3;   //months
    fprintf(f1, "guarantee:%i mon\t", s[5].guarantee );
    s[5].voltage=220;
    fprintf(f1, "\tvoltage:%i V\t", s[5].voltage );
    s[5].amperage=550;
    fprintf(f1, "amperage:%i A", s[5].amperage );
    s[5].frequency=310;
    fprintf(f1, "  frequency:%i Hz", s[5].frequency );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fwrite(&s[0],sizeof(device),1,f1)`?

Comment: ошибка: структура device незадиклорирована

Comment: А вы пробовали? оно же у вас вообще не компилируемо! Одно `s[0].name[20]="Kitchen blender";` чего стоит... Ну ладно, раз вы из тех редких программистов, кто реально код компилирует как С, а не С++, добавьте `sruct`: `fwrite(&s[0],sizeof(struct device),1,f1);`